# Editing Premission denied on Windows 10 File

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 20.10

I'm using `Windows 10` and `Ubuntu` OS on my machine. I use `Ubuntu` mainly for python and servers.

I used the cloud for syncing files between both operating systems because `ubuntu` can access `windows 10` files but it cannot edit them.

is there any way to edit the python scripts in the `windows 10` drive?

> PS: I don't wanna use `Windows 10`'s `WSL` as it has some constraints in my work.

Comment: You should provide more details about your specific problem. Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS file systems so it's not clear what is the problem.

Comment: "Is there any way to edit the python scripts in the windows 10 drive?"  Of course. I do it for a living ... coding using windows and linux to edit html. JS and python.  Why would you not be able to? Just mind that you set your editor to correctly handle line endings.

Comment: If you do a google search for “mount NTFS on Linux” you will get plenty of hits for guides about how to do it. You can do it for a one off session with the mount command or you can add a line to your /etc/fstab file so it mounts automatically at boot. Be aware that NTFS partitions don’t support file permissions like Linux does.

Comment: One other thought, if you hibernate your Windows session the Windows disk will be locked and Linux will not be able to write to it. Similarly if fast boot is enabled the Windows disk is locked when you shut Windows down. Avoid both of these situations and Linux can happily share files with Windows

Comment: @PonJar Thanks a lot to you guys. Yes, my windows files were locked because of hibernation and fastboot. I disabled the fast boot option and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: @PonJar I wanna mark your reply as an answer. Please add your response in the answer section. RESPECT!

Comment: Your thanks is very much appreciated. I’m happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hibernate your Windows session the Windows disk will be locked and Linux will not be able to write to it. Similarly if fast boot is enabled the Windows disk is locked when you shut Windows down. Avoid both of these situations and Linux can happily share files with Windows